# changing the partition of a linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, virtualbox, size

I have a ubuntu system as a virtual system on Virtual Box. It uses VHD as its hard disk.
I manged to change the size of VHD using VHD resizer, now I want to expand the partition on vhd so it uses the expanded size. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Expanding a partition and filesystem size is fairly straightforward, but it will need to be done from inside a live environment, unless it's on LVM. LVM supports online resizing of partition.

From inside a live cd, you can uses `parted` or a parted front-end such as `gparted`. The partition that you are trying to resize must be at the end of the disk. Here is an example for a single partition setup that spans an entire disk:

```
parted /dev/sda1 resize 0 -1
```

Once the partition is extended, you still need to extend the filesystem. If it is ext2/3/4, you can use resize2fs. Here is an example:

```
resize2fs /dev/sda1
```

Without any options, `resize2fs` will extend a filesystem to use all available space on the partition.

Comment: I can not change the size of partion as it says that it is locked. Its type is ext4. what that means?

Comment: @user654019 - Is the VM booted into a liveCD? Are you root? What says it's "locked"? What is the ***exact*** error message?